# Rails bootstrap gem created css problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Okay I am running into a bit of an issue. When I am using the gem the page renders as below. However when I include the link to the actual bootstrap css stylesheet, the navbar shows up correctly. Any idea what could be causing this problem? I have overridden nothing and don't intend on doing so.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should add your CSS file that you are using

Comment: Can you show us your `Gemfile` and `application.css` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my own fault. Assets weren't being loaded since I hadn't restarted my rails server after making some changes to the gem file..